# When I compile NodeJS, I get an compile error

Tags: javascript, node.js

In `mymodule.js`

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')
module.exports = function(dir, extension, callback){
    fs.readdir(dir, function(error, files){
        if(error)
            return callback(error)
        else {
            var res = files.filter(function(file){ return path.extname(file).slice(1) === extension;});
            callback(null, res)
         }
    }
}
```

In `program.js`:

```
   var mymodule = require("./mymodule")
   var path  = require("path")
   var dirname = process.argv[2]
   var extension = process.argv[3]

   mymodule(dirname, extension, function(error, files){
               if(!error)
                   console.log(files);
            }
```

when I run `node program.js /home/elqstux/ "erl"`, there is a compile error:

```
/home/elqstux/javascripting/mymodule.js:12
}
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/elqstux/javascripting/program.js:1:78)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

But I can not find the reason, who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing `});` at the end of your file.

It should be:

```
mymodule(dirname, extension, function(error, files){
    if (!error) {
        console.log(files);
    }
}); // <--- here
```

Proper indentation, inclusion of `;` (even if they're optional), and `{}` for `if` statements makes programs more readable.

You can also use tools like JSLint or JSHint which may help in finding this kind of errors and misspellings before you actually run the program.

Comment: which file? i find they all match

Answer (score 1):

In `mymodule.js` as the error states you need a `);` after here:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')
module.exports = function(dir, extension, callback){
    fs.readdir(dir, function(error, files){
        if(error)
            return callback(error)
        else {
            var res = files.filter(function(file){ return path.extname(file).slice(1) === extension;});
            callback(null, res)
         }
    }); /* here */
}
```

Comment: Nice catch. Haven't noticed that one.